# Как убрать подсветку кода при ошибках в intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

тыкался в inspections и так и не нашел, как убрать эту волнистую линию. Нужно полностью убрать чтобы не подсказывала IDE мои ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как это сделать пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел такое ([обсуждение](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206151809-Any-way-to-disable-or-change-syntax-error-highlighting-for-the-current-line-)). Вы можете установить очень большое время вывода этой ошибки:

```
Settings|Editor|General - Error Highlighting - Autoreparse delay
```

Так же можно отключить inspections как указано в [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html) к IDE.

Comment: Не получается для мак бука сделать :/, отключаю всё, но всё равно горит красным :/

Comment: а перезагрузить если еще потом?

Comment: всё равно не работает :/

Comment: а где вы отключаете? я вот для примера перешел в android studio preferences->editor->inspections и там будет список того что вы можете отключить